# Performing a within sub-group aggregate calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

I want to calculate 'within group quotas`using the bottom`N` values. I've read through several examples [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#101) which explains a lot of different ways of calculating this measure, but I don't fully understand them (and some are not specific to Postgresql). I'm using the following table to illustrate my question:

```
    a | b | x
   ---|---|------
    1 | 1 | 10.00
    1 | 2 | 15.00
    1 | 1 | 10.00
    1 | 2 | 15.00
    2 | 2 | 20.00
    2 | 1 | 21.00
    2 | 2 | 18.00
```

`SQL` to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a int,b int,x decimal(6,2));
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,1,10),(1,2,15), (1,1,10), (1,2,15), (2,2,20),(2,1,21),(2,2,18);
```

I want to be able to calculate the minimum of the lowest `N` values, per group. In this example, I am letting `N = 2`. The first step that I have tried is the following:

```
SELECT 
  t1.a,  
  AVG(t1.x) as avg_x
FROM 
  test AS t1
GROUP BY t1.a
ORDER BY avg_x
```

which returns:

```
a | avg_x
--|------
1 | 12.50
2 | 19.66
```

What I've tried doing (which give the incorrect result) is to make a subquery, and to limit the number of results:

```
SELECT foo.* FROM 
(SELECT 
  t1.a,  
  AVG(t1.x) as avg_x
FROM 
  test AS t1
GROUP BY t1.a
ORDER BY avg_x
) as foo
ORDER BY foo.avg_x
LIMIT 2
```

I know this is not correct, as it is not using the `LIMIT` per sub-group. To clarify the table that I want returned is:

```
a | avg_x
--|------
1 | 10.00
2 | 19.00
```

The raw result for `a=1` is `x = 10.0, 10.0, 21`, with average of the values `10.0, 10.0`.

Comment: I got a bit confused. From the initial table, what is the expected result (as a table) that you're looking for?

Comment: One more thing, what is the primary key?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - I tried to re-explain this again. In this example I was not using a primary key.

Comment: How are you calculating `15.00` for `a = 2`? is this a typo? shouldn't it be `(18 + 20)/2 = 19.00`?

Comment: sorry - typo! My mistake. Fixed it (and thanks for your elegant solution).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this will work in PostgreSQL:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY x) AS rnk
    FROM @yourTable AS A
) 
SELECT a, AVG(x) avg_lowest_n_values
FROM T
WHERE rnk <= 2
GROUP BY a;
```

Comment: `b` first, and then `a`. Does that make sense? Your solution does work numerically (I'm just trying to wrap my head around the syntax).

Comment: @celenius - You are grouping by `b` then `a`? That does not make sense, you would end up with 4 result records not two: (a=1, b=1), (a=1,b=2), (a=2, b=1), (a=2, b=2).

Comment: You're right.... I'm just realizing this. I'm just grouping by `a`, the value of `b` is not actually considered at all. I'll re-edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.a, round(AVG(t1.x), 2) as avg_x
FROM (SELECT * 
     FROM test t2
     WHERE x in (select x
                 from test t3
                 where t3.a = t2.a
                 order by x
                 limit 2)) as t1
GROUP BY t1.a
ORDER BY avg_x
```

**Result:**

```
a | avg_x
--+-------
1 | 10.00
2 | 19.00
```

If I understood your question correctly.